# Why do my temperatur sensors became suddenly instable?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors

I have four DS18B20 temperature sensors connected to my Raspberry Pi. I use 1wire and a pull-up resistor.

I read the values directly via `cat` from the 1wire devices and put the velues without calculation into a gnuplot data file.

The setup has been running fine for weeks now, measuring a coolbox at different places in a range between about 0°C and 30°C. I got quite accurate readings and plots.

**But suddenly the values of all sensors start to "flutter", the became unstable**. They also dropped -- all four -- about quarter of a °C. The flutter is about about 0.1°C to 0.2°C. Two of the sensors are actually inside fluid (0.5l and 25l) and thus it is virtually impossible that they suddenly drop or flutter.

The time of the event coincides with me checking the cooler box. I might have shifted or touched some sensoring parts. But can that explain the temperature shift? What happend? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that somehow the resolution got changed? Have you tried setting it back to 12 bits?

Comment: @JacekŚlimok I did not log on to the Pi, all scripts run automatic. Also, I didn't even know I could change he resolution. That would require some write to registers? http://www.homautomation.org/2015/11/17/ds18b20-how-to-change-resolution-9101112-bits/ I could not imagine how that could have happened. I suppose they are reset after a reboot?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it was the driver that set the resolution. As for the sensor - the datasheet states that the default resolution after power-up is 12 bits. I'd check the fluctuating values whether they fall only into a value range of a lower resolution, e.g. change only in 0.25 degree steps.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok You know what? It seems your suspicion was right. After rebooting things got back to normal. But: a) that must have happened spontanously (i.e. no login), b) I have no proof that it was reduced resolution but I think the graph fits to that hypotheses. Make your suspicion an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: How do I vote this question to be moved to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You can probably flag the question as 'in need of moderator intervention' if you're determined :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a cause of the problem could be resolution being lowered. This is a (volatile) setting stored in the sensor itself. It can be set to 9, 10, 11 or 12 bits. The higher the resolution the more precise the measurements will be, but at a cost of longer measurement time.

According to DS18B20 datasheet, by default the resolution is set to 12 bits after power up. In addition, the drivers handling 1-wire communication with the sensor often also by default set highest possible resolution during startup. This could explain why rebooting fixed the problem in case of OP, but doesn't explain why the change in resolution happened in the first place. That likely depends on the specific setup and will likely have to be resolved on a case-by-case basis.

Furthermore - to confirm that the measurements are indeed done at lower resolution, one can get the numeric values of the samples and check the minimum value by which the measurements change. For example, for 12bit resolution the minimum delta is 0.0625 degrees, while for 9bit resolution it may only change by 0.5 degree and nothing in between.